# Как в tkinter сохранять мастштаб кнопок, текста и т.д?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

При уменьшение размера окна текст, кнопки и т.д могут скрываться

Comment: Попробуйте через `.place`. но оно тоже не всегда работает

Answer (score 1):

### Можно сделать через `.place(...)`:

Делать это надо будет через `relwidth, relheight, rely, relx`

### Вот список параметров:

**Основными параметрами place являются:**

- anchor (якорь) – определяет часть виджета, для которой задаются
  координаты. Принимает значения N, NE, E, SE, SW, W, NW или CENTER. По
  умолчанию NW (верхний левый угол).
- relwidth, relheight (относительные ширина и высота) – определяют
  размер виджета в долях его родителя.
- relx, rely – определяют относительную позицию в родительском виджете.
  Координата (0; 0) – у левого верхнего угла, (1; 1) – у правого
  нижнего.
- width, height – абсолютный размер виджета в пикселях. Значения по
  умолчанию (когда данные опции опущены) приравниваются к естественному
  размеру виджета, то есть к тому, который определяется при его
  создании и конфигурировании.
- x, y – абсолютная позиция в пикселях. Значения по умолчанию
  приравниваются к нулю.

Скописастил с этого замечательного сайта [Tkinter - Place Younglinux.info](https://younglinux.info/tkinter/place)